# How do I update Wagtail to the latest release?

Tags: wagtail

I'm new to Wagtail and I got as far as being able to create an account and now I have access to http://127.0.0.1:8000/. That said the banner informed me that I have the 1.3 version and I need to upgrade to 1.10. I looked at all the release notes but there were no instructions. How do I go about this? Thank you!

Comment: Nitpick: If you have 1.3 and want 1.10, you **downgrade**, not **upgrade**

Comment: If these were decimal _numbers_, that would be true, but it's probably more helpful to think of version numbers like these as _decimal-separated tuples_.

Comment: David Oliver's answer works perfectly as of Wagtail 2.7 (2019)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106728/12354024

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wagtail is a Python module, and is found at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wagtail/. You can install version 1.10.1 on a typical Linux/Unix/Mac OS system with

```bash
$ pip install wagtail==1.10.1
```

Or you can always upgrade to the latest with `pip install --upgrade wagtail`.

This isn't a Wagtail-specific question, so I suggest looking at pip itself if you want some further reading: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new to Wagtail and am not particularly familiar with Python dependency management. Using the documentation to which nimasmi linked I updated to the latest release with the following commands.

```
$ # See which packages are outdated
$ pip list --outdated

$ # Update Wagtail and its dependencies
$ pip install --upgrade wagtail

$ # Run database migrations
$ python manage.py migrate

$ # Record new package versions in requirements file
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: I don't recommend a blanket running of `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. If your package has many dependencies, then crystallising them now will store noise in requirements, mean more things to amend when you next need to upgrade, and risk overwriting any custom versions you had already specified. I recommend adding to requirements.txt only those results from pip freeze that you have intentionally installed, e.g. `pip install --upgrade wagtail` followed by `pip freeze | grep Wagtail >> requirements.txt`, followed by manually ordering and replacing the line in requirements.txt.